# JavaScript: Check if string variable is in text

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

I have a text string and an array of words. I am trying to see if the words appear in the text and if they do put them in another array.

I have tried:

```
var aray = ['dies','jam', 'jug', 'march', 'one', 'men', 'all'],
testText = "If one of them dies I will notice that one off my men is missing"
i,found = [];

for(i=0; i < aray.length; i++){
    searchTerm = "/\\b" + aray[i] + "/gi";
    found = testText.match(searchTerm)
}
```

But found is always "null"

I read that maybe I should construct a new RegExp object, so I tried:

```
for(i=0; i < aray.length; i++){
    searchTerm = "/\\b" + aray[i] + "/gi";
    found = testText.match(new RegExp(searchTerm, 'gi'));
}
```

But still found = "null". I have tried changing the regex but if I put the regex directly into the testText.match it works, ie:

```
searchTerm = "/\\b" + 'dies' + "/gi";
```

Comment: If you want to use a variable in RegEx pattern in JavaScript you must use the `New RegExp()` like this: `var searchTerm = new RegExp("\\b" + aray[i] + "\\b", "gi");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#intersection) or a [custom array intersection function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript):

```
var array = ['dies','jam', 'jug', 'march', 'one', 'men', 'all'],
testText = "If one of them dies I will notice that one off my men is missing";

var diff = _.intersection(array, testText.split(' '));

console.log(diff);
```

--> `["dies", "one", "men"]`

http://jsfiddle.net/S65Vd/1/

Comment: Sorry I mean intersection, difference is the opposite

Comment: Thanks, that works. It is something new to me and I will have to find out why it works :-)